# What am I missing on Appending this decimal to my Number Pad?

Tags: iphone

I've been staring at this issue for the past week. Countless cups of Joe, cats stepping on my keyboard, and girlfriend wanting me to get off of the laptop later - I still can't figure this out. Hoping I'm doing something very stupid (100% chance) that I'm over looking.

I have some code which appends a decimal to the number pad. Most of the code was taken from here (http://brygruver.squarespace.com/blog/2009/10/1/creating-a-custom-number-pad.html?lastPage=true&postSubmitted=true) and I'm using his code but modified it a bit to only append the decimal and image of the decimal to the last two fields of my total five fields.

Here is my code which is showing the decimal image and appending it to the input:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    // We need to access the dot Button declared in the Delegate.
    helloAppDelegate *appDelegate = (helloAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    // Only if we are editing within the Number Pad Text Field do we want the dot.
    if (textField == txtUserName4) {
        // Show the Dot.
        appDelegate.dot.hidden = NO;
    } 
    else if (textField == txtUserName5) {
        // Show the Dot.
        appDelegate.dot.hidden = NO;
    } 
    else {
        // Otherwise, Hide the Dot.
        appDelegate.dot.hidden = YES;
    }
}

- (void)addDecimal:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Apend the Decimal to the TextField.
    if (txtUserName4.editing) {
        txtUserName4.text = [txtUserName4.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];
    }
    else if (txtUserName5.editing) {
        txtUserName5.text = [txtUserName5.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];
    }
```

here is a video of what's happening (http://screencast.com/t/OTNhODRiYjAt). The decimal isn't showing *unless I bring up the alert error*, and then it shows correctly for both the fields.

SO, I turned off the field validation and - shocking - the decimal shows on the last two fields (http://screencast.com/t/ZmQyOTc1MT). So it must not be the code showing the decimals but the validation I have.

here is the validation I have. I'm thinking I'm dropping the ball with the text field being nil or being first responder?

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{   
    if (textField == txtUserName)
    {
        NSString *userNameOne = txtUserName.text;
        double numOne = [userNameOne doubleValue];  

        if(numOne < 30 || numOne > 80)
        {

            //show alert
            //release alert

            //if there is alert then clear out the field and make that the FR


            [txtUserName becomeFirstResponder];
            txtUserName.text = nil;
        }
        else 
        {
            [txtUserName2 becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    }

    else if (textField == txtUserName2)
    {

        NSString *userNameThree = txtUserName2.text;
        float numTwo = [userNameThree doubleValue]; 

        if (numTwo < 20 || numTwo > 32)
        {
            //show alert
            //release alert

            //if there is alert then clear out the field and make that the FR


            [txtUserName2 becomeFirstResponder];
            txtUserName2.text = nil;
        }
        else
        {
            [txtUserName3 becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    }
    else if (textField == txtUserName3)
    {
        NSString *userNameThree = txtUserName3.text;
        float numThree = [userNameThree doubleValue];

        if (numThree < 475 || numThree > 650)
        {
            //show alert
            //release alert

            //if there is alert then clear out the field and make that the FR


            [txtUserName3 becomeFirstResponder];
            txtUserName3.text = nil;
        }
        else
        {
            [txtUserName4 becomeFirstResponder];

        }
    }
    else if (textField == txtUserName4)
    {
        NSString *userNameFour = txtUserName4.text; 
        double numFour = [userNameFour doubleValue];

        if (numFour < 0.5 || numFour > 3.00)
        {

            //show alert
            //release alert

            //if there is alert then clear out the field and make that the FR


            [txtUserName4 becomeFirstResponder];
            txtUserName4.text = nil;
        }
        else
        {
            [txtUserName5 becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    }
    else if (textField == txtUserName5)
    {
        NSString *userNameFive = txtUserName5.text;
        double numFive = [userNameFive doubleValue];

        if (numFive > 0.80)
        {
            //show alert
            //release alert

            //if there is alert then clear out the field and make that the FR
            [txtUserName5 becomeFirstResponder];
            txtUserName5.text = nil;
        }
        else
        {
            [txtUserName5 resignFirstResponder];
        }
    }
}
```

I'm really stumped but at least figured out it's something with my validation mixing things up...

EDIT: 
I found out if I comment out the `else` that makes the next field the first responder, then everything works as it should.

With that said, does removing the `else` really hurt anything in my validation? This entire validation was made with the idea of using the 'done' and 'next' buttons back when I was using the basic keyboard. Now, I'm seeing that my entire validation code is lacking a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely when you call `-becomeFirstResponder`, the keyboard is getting redrawn, which likely is pushing the keyboard view above your magical "dot" view that is supposed to be floating on top. You probably need to call `-bringSubviewToFront:` with your "dot" view whenever you switch first responder.